# What is the pythonic way of generating this type of list? (Faces of an n-cube)

Tags: python, list, geometry, tuples

```
if n == 1: return [(-1,),    (1,)]
if n == 2: return [(-1,0),   (1,0),   (0,-1),   (0,1)]
if n == 3: return [(-1,0,0), (1,0,0), (0,-1,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,-1), (0,0,1)]
```

Basically, return a list of `2n` tuples conforming to the above specification. The above code works fine for my purposes but I'd like to see a function that works for all n ∈ ℕ (just for edification). Including `tuple([0]*n)` in the answer is acceptable by me.

I'm using this to generate the direction of faces for a measure polytope. For all directions, I can use `list(itertools.product(*[(0, -1, 1)]*n))`, but I can't come up with something quite so concise for only the face directions.

Comment: I'd probably stop thinking about it and use a `for` loop.

Comment: Ehm.. *"Code Golf is no longer on-topic for Stack Overflow"*.

Comment: @arshajii: it's not strictly golf. As you can see, the top voted answer is not golf.

Comment: Then the code-golf tag should be removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def faces(n):
    def iter_faces():
        f = [0] * n
        for i in range(n):
            for x in (-1, 1):
                f[i] = x
                yield tuple(f)
            f[i] = 0
    return list(iter_faces())
```

---

```
>>> faces(1)
[(-1,), (1,)]
>>> faces(2)
[(-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)]
>>> faces(3)
[(-1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0, -1, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, -1), (0, 0, 1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[tuple(sign * (i == p) for i in range(n)) for p in range(n) for sign in (-1, 1)]
```

Plain `for`, no implicit `bool`→`int` equivalent:

```
for p in range(n):
    for sign in (-1, 1):
        yield tuple((sign if i == p else 0) for i in range(n))
```

Comment: One-liner, but takes a bit to figure out, and 3 `for` clauses is a bit much.

Answer (score 3):

The way I am seeing this problem is two simultaneous interleaving `n` sized shift registers

```
>>> def shift_register(n):
    l1 = (-1,) + (0,)*(n - 1)
    l2 = (1,) +  (0,)*(n - 1)
    while any(l1):
        yield l1
        yield l2
        l1 = (0,) + l1[:-1]
        l2 = (0,) + l2[:-1]


>>> list(shift_register(3))
[(-1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0, -1, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, -1), (0, 0, 1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution using `numpy`:

```
>>> a = numpy.identity(3, dtype=int)
>>> numpy.hstack((a, -a)).reshape(6, 3)
array([[ 1,  0,  0],
       [-1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  0],
       [ 0, -1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1],
       [ 0,  0, -1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> set(itertools.permutations([1] + [0]*(n-1))) | set(itertools.permutations([-1] + [0]*(n-1)))
```

Comment: Superexponential runtime makes this a bad idea. Also, the resulting tuples have a `0` too many.

Comment: Fixed the `n` thing.  Answer is obviously unfit for large `n`, but I'll leave it up.